# Could you please help on a replaceAll Java with regex example below

Tags: java, regex, str-replace

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("( see the example pattern )");
Matcher matcher=p.matcher(text);
String result=matcher.replaceAll("");
```

i.e.

- 2009-10-05T13:44:34+0000
- 2011-03-13T23:59:24+0000
- 2010-10-11-09T15:39:37+0000
- 2009-10-05T13:44:34+0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}T\\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\+\\d{4}"
```

Comment: Thank you John for the quick response - The regex worked perfectly.. Thanks again

Comment: @HollySmith ... Then 'accept' the answer ;) As for myself, I do not understand why one should escape '`-`'  (`\\-` parts)